# How to join queries with AND in elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index with this mapping:

```
{
  "SampleIndex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "$type" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "data" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        
        "id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "isActive" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "isDeleted" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "ownerSSN" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "ownerId" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "type" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

now I want to create this query:

> select * From SampleIndex where ownerSSN = "someSNN" and  ownerId =
> "someOwnerId" and type = 1

I try to produce my query by this code using NEST:

```
var result = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<BankAccountReadModel>(
                    s => s
                    .Index(IndexName)
                    .Query(q =>
                                q.ByOwnerId(personageId) &&
                                q.ByOwnerSSN(nationalCode) &&
                                q.ByType(type)
                   ));

            return result.Hits.Select(x => x.Source).ToList();
```

and my Extension methods are listed below:

```
 internal static class BankAccountFilterExtention {
        public static QueryContainer ByOwnerId(
            this QueryContainerDescriptor<BankAccountReadModel> search
            , Guid? id) {
            if (id.HasValue)
                return search.Term(x =>
                x.PersonageId, id.Value.ToString());
            return null; 
        }

        public static QueryContainer ByOwnerSSN(
            this QueryContainerDescriptor<BankAccountReadModel> search
            , string nationalId)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nationalId))
                return search.Term(x =>
                    x.OwnerNationalCode,nationalId
                );
            return null;
        }

        public static QueryContainer ByType(
            this QueryContainerDescriptor<BankAccountReadModel> search,
            BankAccountType? type)
        {
            if (type.HasValue)
            {
                search.Term(b=> b.Type,type.Value);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I expect that when I run this query by "SomeSSN" and type = 1 this retrieves only the records which match both of these values. but I am getting each record those have "someSSN" or type =1.

how can I correct my query?

Comment: note that in `ByType` you're not returning the term query.

Comment: this was so foolish... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ByType` you're not returning the term query

```
    public static QueryContainer ByType(
        this QueryContainerDescriptor<BankAccountReadModel> search,
        BankAccountType? type)
    {
        if (type.HasValue)
        {
            return search.Term(b=> b.Type,type.Value);    <--- change this
        }
        return null;
    }
```